Confluence: different appearance when not logged in
in our corporate Confluence anonymous (not logged in) users have read access to the public contents.
The page appearance is the same, only with reduced navigation and no edit functionality.
This confuses me every time: I forget to log in, then ask for the permission (or whether the structure has changed) - just to learn that I only need to log in.
Is there a way to change the application's appearance when not logged in, e.g. add a colored line to the header?
I expect to see that I am not logged in without having to think about it.
Kind regards
Dennis
